# How to specify a class's comparator in a std::multiset

Tags: c++

I want to create a multiset of objects of my own Class with a custom comparator, and every example I have seen out there does it without classes.

The code I have so far `main.cpp` is like this:

```
multiset<MyClass> myMultiSet;
```

whereas in `Myclass.cpp` there is a comparator function:

```
bool MyClass::operator<(const MyClass c) const {
    return (this->data->size() < c.size());
}
```

Multiset seems to take the `less` operator by default, and it actually uses the `operator<` function in the class, but I cannot find a way to specify it to use another operator (such as `operator<=`)

For example, I would like it to look like this:

```
multiset<MyClass, MyClass::operator<=> myMultiSet;
```

```
bool MyClass::operator<=(const MyClass c) const { // <----- Now it's using this one
    return (this->data->size() <= c.size());
}
```

Comment: Your operator does not implement [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare), you are not allowed to use it as comparator for `std::multiset`. If you want to do that anyway and have Undefined Behaviour, you can use [`std::less_equal<MyClass>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_equal).

Comment: Oh, I see, I did not know about strict weak ordering. Thank you for the warning!

Answer (score 0):

Member functions are different to functions: they take an the `this` pointer. As a result, you can't use pointer-to-member-functions directly (and you would need to take the address explicitly as member functions don't decay to pointer-to-member-functions, i.e., `&MyClass::operator<=`). Also, the parameter is type, not a value. Also, as was pointed out, `operator<=` doesn't implement a strict weak order, i.e., you can't use that anyway.

The easiest to use an actual operator, whether member of not, is to use the names from `<functional>`, e.g.

```
std::multiset<MyClass, std::greater<MyClass>> s;
```

If the member isn't a known name, I'd think using a lambda is the easiest approach but requires C++20:

```
std::multiset<MyClass, decltype([](MyClass const&l, MyClass const&r){ return l.member(r); })> s;
```

Without C++20 I think you can use `std::mem_fn` although that is slightly annoying as you'll need to provide the pointer to member as a constructor argument:

```
#include <functional>
#include <set>

struct MyClass
{
    bool member(MyClass const&) const { return false; }
};

int main()
{
    std::multiset<MyClass, decltype(std::mem_fn(&MyClass::member))> s(std::mem_fn(&MyClass::member));
}
```